# Como recuperar documentos de uma coleção do Firestore(Firebase) da maneira correta?

Tags: array, angular, firebase, firestore, angular-fire-2

Quero recuperar todos os documentos de uma coleção interna de um documento no Firestore para um array, no caso essa coleção tem 2 documentos, no entanto após rodar o código abaixo o console.log() aponta um array com 3 elementos, os dois documentos e mais um Observable que não tenho a mínima ideia de onde é que vem.

```
let imagens: Array<any> = [];

    this.db.collection('contatos').doc(key).collection('imagens')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .forEach(elem => {
         elem.map(c => imagens.push({ key: c.payload.doc.id, ...c.payload.doc.data() }));
      })
    console.log('imagens',imagens);
```

console:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me explicar de onde vem esse Observable e qual a melhor forma para recuperar todos os documentos dessa coleção.

Observação: estou desenvolvendo em Angular 7 e usando Angularfire2 para fazer a integração com o Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables é como o angular lida com asincronismo.

```
let imagens: Array<any> = [];

this.db.collection('contatos').doc(key).collection('imagens')
  .snapshotChanges()
   .subscribe(response=> {
   imagens=[...response] // ou só  imagens=response
   console.log('imagens',imagens);
})
```

Comment: Cara, meu sonho é ser foda que nem você. Consegui o que queria com a sua ajuda, fiz só algumas alterações para satisfazer ao que eu queria, mas a sua dica foi fundamental, valeu.

Answer (score 0):

COnsegui o que queria com a ajuda do Eduardo Vargas, e o meu código ficou assim:

```
this.db.collection('contatos').doc(key).collection('imagens')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .subscribe(response=> {
        imagens=[response.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.doc.id, ...c.payload.doc.data() }))];
        console.log('imagens',imagens);
      });
```